# How to get a unified coverage report with Cobertura + Sonar + Multi-module maven project where the reactor is not the parent POM?

Tags: maven, code-coverage, sonarqube, cobertura, multi-module

We have a setup where we have a multi module maven project, where the reactor POM is not the parent of the individual module POMs - and we can't change that. We're using Cobertura, as we use PowerMock for our unit tests. (we were using JaCoCo before, and that supported generating a single report, but it can't report code coverage for PowerMock enabled unit tests, so we had to swap it out.)

Now, we were wondering: how do we get a single (unified) test coverage report for the entire project in Sonar when we use Cobertura?

Comment: In that case, the question is more "How to merge all Cobertura reports into one report in order to feed SonarQube with this unified report ?"

Comment: You can have a look at this thread to achieve what @FreddyMallet-SonarSource suggested : http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Code-coverage-report-for-multi-module-maven-project-reports-zero-in-some-modules-td5712588.html

Comment: In the end, we found a way to get the PowerMock coverage displayed with JaCoCo (not preparing the class under test for test with PowerMock), so we decided to stick with that. Thanks everyone for your help! :)